# Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and now I see dead black screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, upgrade, dpkg

Timeline:

- I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04.
- It successfully upgraded with some errors related to python. So, I `reboot` the system. (that was my mistake)
- Now I see: `/dev/sda8: clean, xxxx/xxxxx files, xxxx/xxxxx blocks` and never ending black screen.
- I pressed `Alt+Ctrl+F1` for the command line. I **followed and tried many askubuntu posts for the solution** like reinstalling python2.7, `apt-get dpkg`, `sudo apt-get -f install` etc. But, no solutions seem to be working for my problem.

When I do `sudo apt-get -f install`, I see:

```
ImportError: No module named _struct
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
```

and it generates from files `runpy.py`, `compileall.py`, and `struct.py` located in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`.

EDIT:

I also see `~bash: /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: No such file or directory` after I log in.

**EDIT2:**   As the `pastebinit` installation is also not working, I have tried to write the error by myself.

```
.....
.....
Need to get 0 B/13.4 MB of archives    
After this operation, 44.7 MB of additional disk space will be used       
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y     
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.11-1)...      

Traceback (most recent call last):      

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main   
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)    
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code    
exec code in run_globals
File"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
import struct
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>   
from _struct import *

ImportError: No module named _struct   
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):   
subprocess installed [pst-installation script returned error exit status 1      
Errors were encountered while processing:
   python-minimal

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**EDIT3:**

`lsb_release -a` output:

```
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 
Release: 16.04   
Codename: xenial
```

`apt-cache policy python-minimal` output:

```
python-minimal:    
   Installed: 2.7.11-1     
   Candidate: 2.7.11-1     
   Version table:    
  *** 2.7.11-1 500   
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages   
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f`? See [How can I easily share the output of a command or a text file with others?](/q/152371/175814) for a simple way to do that without a graphical user interface.

Comment: @DavidFoerster When I do `sudo apt-get install pastebinit` I get `unmet dependencies` error.  The system suggests to run `apt-get -f install` with no packages. When I do that it goes back to the error `ImportError: No module named _struct`. So I can not even share the output of a command!

Comment: @DavidFoerster I just wrote the error lines in EDIT2.

Comment: `lsb_release -a` output=======    `No LSB modules are available.`    `Distributor ID: Ubuntu`  `Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` `Release: 16.04 ` `Codename: xenial`

Comment: @DavidFoerster apt-cache output:=========    `python-minimal:`   `Installed: 2.7.11-1`  `Candidate: 2.7.11-1`    `Version table:   *** 2.7.11-1 500`            `500    http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`   `100   /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: @DavidFoerster Sure. I shall update in a minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54185/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-mat-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During out chat the issue turned out to be a set of spurious Python modules in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` that overshadowed the ones in `/usr/lib/python2.7` and prevented the successful installation of the new Python packages and every other package that depends on them. The solution was to

1. delete the “local” Python modules,

   ```
   sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7
   ```
2. remove some low-priority packages that blocked the upgrade process,

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove texlive\*
   ```
3. resume the package upgrade process.

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f
   ```

For good measure we also removed the leftover packages of Ubuntu Trusty's hardware enablement stack:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove \*-lts-xenial linux-\*-3.\*
```